# Interpreation - Log tranformed dependant variable and model with square term of predictor (inverted U)

Tags: regression, marginal-effect, back-transformation

I am estimating a model of the following form:

```
log(y) =  b1 x + b2 x^2 + b3 log(z1) + b4 z2
```

This is an econometric model with a focus on the impact of `x` `x^2` (the inverted U relationship), where `x` ranges from 0 to 1. I included the other variables `z1 and z2` just to be clear that there are other controls (some which are log-transformed and some not).

I get a clear inverted U relationship - slope check at end points and a marginal plot confirms that.

My question is the following: How can I say something about the change in x impacting y (not log(y))? This article (https://library.virginia.edu/data/articles/interpreting-log-transformations-in-a-linear-model) provides a nice way to interpret in case I don't have the `x^2` term. How to do this correctly when I have the `x^2` term?

For example, if I am able to do one of the following that will be wonderful:

- If x increases by 0.1 from its current sample mean what will be impact on y?
- If x increases by 10% from its current sample mean, what will be the impact on y?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the following approach will work. Comments and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Now, if I evaluate `log(y1) = log(y)` evaluated at `x=x1` and `log(y2) = log(y)` evaluated at `x=x2`, then

```
log(y2) - log(y1) = -b1 x1 - b2 x1^2 + b1 x2 + b2 x2^2
```

Taking exponents on both sides and simplifying:

```
y2/y1 = Exp(-b1 x1 - b2 x1^2 + b1 x2 + b2 x2^2)
```

So, if I now substitute b1, b2 coefficients and select two points x1 and x2 (`x2>x1`, and both are smaller than the inflection point) in the RHS, can I then interpret that as the ratio between `y2/y1`?

Say, that the ratio is evaluated as 1.4, then can I state that moving x from x1 to x2, yields a 40% increase in y?

From my experiments with predicted values, this does work out. However, I am concerned that I am making any errors by not considering standard errors.